# Git merge conflicts in XML files

Tags: xml, git, git-merge, conflict, git-merge-conflict

I'm asking for a Git merge conflict issue in an XML file. So:
I and my team are using Git for version control and our workflow follows the Agile standards. We are doing scrum with biweekly sprints so every two weeks we develop a new number of features for the customer. At the start of every sprint, we plan to develop all the tasks for two weeks and to integrate into a git master branch.

We are using a dedicated design tool that is included in the project and all the information of this tool are exported in .xml files. So far every sprint we've encountered merge conflicts when we are trying to submit some changes into the master branch.

For example, Two guys can affect the same component in this tool and after export their changes, there will be a merge conflict with the same .xml file. So, until now, the best option we know to solve this issue is to integrate changes of a person and after that to rework in design tool with the new .xml file, for the second person.

The merge conflict are often easy to solve but the complexity increase

We tried to prioritize integration line with an excel file, but this seems that is not the best solution and however is that we feel these merges should not require to be resolved manually as I described.

We are looking for improvements in our workflow to avoid such conflicts
An idea would be to lock the .xml file when someone starts to work on the affected component, but it would take more time.

Does anyone have any other ideas for avoiding these problems?

Comment: If they're exported in XML, is the code that exports it, itself in the repository?

Comment: The paper by Nigel Whitaker and Robin La Fontaine recently presented at XML Prague 2019 addresses this issue: http://archive.xmlprague.cz/2019/files/xmlprague-2019-proceedings.pdf